# Caesar Cipher CMD batch, include special characters, numbers, small and capital characters

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I have got [this code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/Q_21494359.html).

My problem is, I need to extend it and add support for numbers, special characters (./-: etc) and capital characters

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Alphabet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set oText=http://randomwebsite.com/rand/206/index.html
set offset=11

call :ENCRYPT %offset% "%oText%"
echo KeySet=%KeySet%
set eText=%outText%
call :DECRYPT %offset% "%eText%"
set dText=%outText%
echo Original text:  %oText%
echo Encrpted text:  %eText%
echo Decrypted text: %dText%
goto :EOF

:ENCRYPT
call :GETKEYSET %1
set _from=%Alphabet%
set _to=%KeySet%
set outText=%~2
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 25) do call :STUFFIT %%a
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 25) do call :PROCESS %%a  
goto :EOF

:DECRYPT
call :GETKEYSET %1
set _from=%KeySet%
set _to=%Alphabet%
set outText=%~2
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 25) do call :STUFFIT %%a
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 25) do call :PROCESS %%a 
goto :EOF

:STUFFIT
set fromChar=!_from:~%1,1!
set outText=!outText:%fromChar%=_%fromChar%!
goto :EOF

:PROCESS
set fromChar=!_from:~%1,1!
set toChar=!_to:~%1,1!
set outText=!outText:_%fromChar%=%toChar%!
goto :EOF

:GETKEYSET
set /a idx=%1 %% 26
set KeySet=!Alphabet:~%idx%!
if %idx%==0 goto :EOF
set KeySet=%KeySet%!Alphabet:~0,%idx%!
```

any idea please? thanks

Comment: Add the desired characters to the `Alphabet` variable and increase the values in the `for /L` loops?

Comment: @SomethingDark in that case decrypted output is HTTP://RA_nDO_nWEBSITE.CO_n/RA_nD/206/I_nDEX.HT_nm

Comment: and If I manage to get correct string, it still does have only small characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my first idea after reviewed your code was put it in the trash can and made it again **`;-)`**

The original code is a curious mix of styles; in one hand, the encryption/decryption methods are pretty rudimentary and closely follows the "manual" method, so the program is very inefficient. On the other hand, the programming style is confusing: in some cases use subroutine parameters, but the subroutine results are returned via global variables, and the variable names seems to be choosen specifically to confuse!

The problem with Capital letters is that they must be separated from the lowercase ones in individual basis, so characters in the string to convert must be processed one by one.

**EDIT**: The code was modified in order to manage strings with exclamation marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Alphabet=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set "lowCase=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

set offset=11

set "oText=something^! is really^! great"
set maxLen=80

call :ENCRYPT %offset% "!oText!" eText=
call :DECRYPT %offset% "!eText!" dText=
echo Original text:  !oText!
echo Encrypted text: !eText!
echo Decrypted text: !dText!
goto :EOF


:ENCRYPT offset "input string" outVar=
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "inString=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (0,1,61) do (
   set /A "i=(%%i + %1) %% 62"
   set c["!Alphabet:~%%i,1!"]=!i!
)
goto CompleteEncryptDecrypt


:DECRYPT offset "input string" outVar=
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "inString=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (0,1,61) do (
   set /A "i=%%i - %1"
   if !i! lss 0 set /A i+=62
   set c["!Alphabet:~%%i,1!"]=!i!
)


:CompleteEncryptDecrypt

set "outVar="
for /L %%i in (0,1,%maxLen%) do (
   set "char=!inString:~%%i,1!"
   if defined char (
      for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!char!") do (
         if defined c["%%c"] (
            set j=!c["%%c"]!
            if "!lowCase:%%c=%%c!" neq "%lowCase%" set /A "j-=26"
            for /F %%j in ("!j!") do set "outVar=!outVar!!Alphabet:~%%j,1!"
         ) else (
            set "outVar=!outVar!!char!"
         )
      )
   )
)

( 
endlocal 
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%outVar:!=^!%") do endlocal & set "%3=%%a"
)
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
Original text:  something! is really! great
Encrypted text: 3zxp4styr! t3 2plww9! r2pl4
Decrypted text: something! is really! great
```

A point to do in this program is to get the string length with a subroutine instead of defining the `set maxLen=80` line, and then eliminate the corresponding `if` command.

Comment: it is working great, thanks, but one more issue, in my original string is for example "something!isreally!great" but it only works with "somethinggreat"

Comment: Yes, but your original code also have this problem! **`:/`** See the edit in my answer!